# Cannot buy house after completing Blood on the Ice through console command

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was trying to buy a house in Windhelm, but ran into a lot of issues.

I did the 5/5 thing, but I took over Windhelm before completing blood on the ice.
I typed `completequest ms11` in console, it worked, but I still cannot buy the house.
To make it even weirder, it shows I completed the quest on screen, but when I look at my completed quests it was not listed there.
Also, my statistics show I have done the quest after I forced it.

I need the house to put armor and swords on because I have way too much and if I give it to my housecarl she uses the weapons that have magic abilities making their effects eventually useless.
Any ways around this?

I have done extensive research and found nothing, is there any way I can `setstage` to a part of the quest to where I can kill the butcher?
Is there any other way to get the house?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but this question and its answer might help you give some insight to what is actually the problem http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232834/can-i-complete-blood-on-ice-if-i-finished-battle-for-windhelm?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

This quest may be bugged, but probably it's working. Have you completed the Civil War questline? You need to complete that to get the house.

Answer (score -1):

guys. I did type an answer somewhere on this website but I can't find it so I'll do it again. This is for pc. There is a fix for this. Found it by accident. I am not a programmer. Was completely stuck with blood on the ice quest. Couldn't go forwards or backwards. Went through civil war as stormcloak. Ulric ended up on the throne. Tried for Hjerim again. This is what you have to do to fix it. On console type in completequest ms11. Then completequest ms11b. Next is VERY important. Won't work without it. Make sure you have enough money to buy Hjerim. Type setstage a7b33 10. Then you can go to Jorlief to start decorating your home. When the options come up, BEFORE you do anything else, choose to have the murderer's mess cleaned up before choosing any other decorating options. If you don't you will end up with a dirty, bloody house. And have to start all over again. After the mess is cleaned up then you can choose other decorating options and the quest will be fixed and you will own the house. Hope this helps.